# Is it dangerous to publish the enode address?

Tags: addresses, nodes, supernodes, enode

Someone mailed me and asked about my supernode ip / enode address. From go ethereum gitter:

> Hello all. I'm running a little over 100MH/s doing solo mining. Atm, we have a very high uncle rate, probably because I haven't altered the bootnodes or default max peers. If I wanted to find nodes across the US/EU to add to the bootnode list, where would I do that?
>
> I can't seem to find the addresses for the supernodes listed on ethstats.

Is it dangerous to share the enode address of my supernode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can already see the enodes (node ID, aka the public key, and IP address) of nodes your node is connected to, for example by typing "admin.peers" into the geth console. So worst case is your node gets more connection attempts than may be desired.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your IP and Enode is already public via [ethernodes.org](http://ethernodes.org).